# With WebAssembly, is there any way to take a .jar and now run it in the browser?

Tags: java, browser, jar, webassembly

My understanding of WebAssembly is a bit finicky, but I've seen projects such as [TeaVM](https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm) and [JWebAssembly](https://github.com/i-net-software/JWebAssembly) which seem to transpile Java bytecode to Webassembly. My question is can any of these tools be used to translate an entire .jar applet into something that can be executed in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no direct conversion.
However, you can use JWebAssembly to refactor your Applet/Java code with some effort and limitations and generate a WebAssembly code.
Therefore, you will need to refactor your applet code (with the language limitations detailed in the project documentation [project status](https://github.com/i-net-software/JWebAssembly#status-of-the-project) and [java limits](https://github.com/i-net-software/JWebAssembly#java-limits)) and rewrite the GUI via the DOM API from the JWebAssembly API project.

As *JWebAssembly* (wiki/FAQ) says:

> Q: Can I compile with JWebAssembly Swing, AWT or Applet applications?
>   A: No, you need to write a GUI via the DOM API from the JWebAssembly
>   API project. In theory, anyone can write a library that implements
>   support for Swing and / or AWT. However, but this is not recommended.

The JWebAssembly conversion is like a 1:1 conversion. The generated WebAssembly code is similar in size to the original .class files.

In this case of TeaVM, more than a direct conversion, you will find a development framework specially designed for Javascript and with currently experimental support for WebAssembly (Wasm). It tries to reconstruct original structure of methods, it has an optimizer that remove dead code, convert virtual calls in static calls, etc.

As *TeaVM* (Github) says:

> WebAssembly support is in experimental status. It may lack major
>   features available in JavaScript backend. There's no documentation yet
>   and you should do many things by hands (like embedding generated wasm
>   file into your page, importing JavaScript objects, etc). Look at
>   samples/benchmark module. You should first examine pom.xml file to
>   learn how to build wasm file from Java. Then you may want to examine
>   index-teavm.html and index-teavm.js to learn how to embed WebAssembly
>   into your web page.

And as the official site says:

> TeaVM is primarily a web development tool. It’s not for taking your
>   large existing codebase in Java or Kotlin and producing JavaScript.
>   Unfortunately, Java was not designed to run efficiently in the
>   browser. There are Java APIs that are impossible to implement without
>   generating inefficient JavaScript. Some of these APIs are: reflection,
>   resources, class loaders, and JNI. TeaVM restricts usage of these
>   APIs. Generally, you’ll have to manually rewrite your code to fit into
>   TeaVM constraints.

You can check this sample project, the java sources (eg. WasmBenchmarkStarter.java) and the pom.xml to see how code is ([sample](https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm/tree/master/samples/benchmark)).

Another similar project is: [bytecoder](https://github.com/mirkosertic/Bytecoder)

Regards